# Code execution cannot proceed because libpthread.dll was not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

After I run my node with `ros2 run ..` I always got a popup saying this:

> The code execution cannot proceed
> because **libpthread.dll** was not found.
> Reinstalling the program may fix the
> problem.

In my code I'm including pthread.h, and since I'm on Windows I downloaded [the sources](https://github.com/coapp-packages/pthreads) from here. Then I retargeted the project and built it as Release x64. So in the end I have **libpthread.lib** and **libpthread.dll** in the same folder.
Now, in my **CMakeLists** I have:

```
include_directories("C:/path_to_pthread.h")
link_directories("C:/path_to_libpthread.lib")
target_link_libraries(name libpthread)
```

I can build my code correctly, but when I run it I got that windows popup. I've also tried to rebuild pthread many times, but it doesn't change anything.

I can't understand why it doesn't find the **.dll** when it is in the exact same folder of the **.lib**, that seems to be found.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397795/code-execution-cannot-proceed-because-libpthread.dll-was-not-found/) by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2022-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try to put your DLL in the system folder and register it? Like [in this FAQ](https://www.dll-files.com/support/#200924305).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-03-21**:
That's what I was missing! thank you!